# Limit range of number to positive in rendered view using html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm building an MVC app and I am trying to limit the range to positive numbers on fields of input type number.

Here's an example:

```
Quantity: <input type="number" value="int" name="quantity"/>
```

This line of code in my View will generate a number field on which the user can click and choose a number. But the number can either go positive and negative and I would like to limit that exclusively to positive numbers.

Any idea how could I do this?

Comment: If you want you can do this with dataAnnotations. [RANGE ATTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx)

Comment: This is more an HTML5 question. You can add `min="0"` to limit input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="number" value="int" name="quantity" min="0"/>`

That's one of cool new HTML5 input types feature.

Comment: It works well! Thank you! Now I wonder if there is any way to "remember" the value in the field after having submitted?